# Tika Parser as runtime dependency in gradle jar

Tags: java, gradle, apache-tika

I have a gradle project where I'm using Tika's AutoDetectParser to extract content. When the project is built into a fat jar, AutoDetectParser returns empty string. I can see this is because Parser is not in the runtime classpath. How do I add Parser to the runtime classpath?

Gradle build file:

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.20'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

jar {
  manifest {
      attributes (
          'Main-Class': 'com.superna.tikatest.TikaTestApp'
      )
  }
  from { 
      configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } 
  } {
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA'
  }
}
```

Code snippet:

```
                Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
                BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();          

                try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(localPath.toString());
                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                        TikaInputStream stream = TikaInputStream.get(bis)) {
                    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
                    System.out.println(handler.toString());
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using shadow plugin to build my jar solved the problem